# Perform grep on elements that start with won't work

Tags: git, grep

I have git branches some starting with "fix-" and others starting with "hotfix-". I want to list only those, that start with "fix-". For this I tried to use: `git branch | grep ^fix` but this wont produce any output. If I do `git branch | grep fix` I get all my branches. It looks like as if there was some other invisible characters before my branch names or I don't know... Could you help me?

Comment: The output from `git branch` includes `* master` if you're on master. The other branch names line up with the `m` in `master`. How many spaces does it take to make `fix` line up with the `m` in `* master`?

Answer (score 1):

There are not invisible characters, but there probably are some visible ones (like the `*` on the current branch, and the spaces on other branches that keep the column neatly lined up.

So one option would be to use a pattern like `^..fix`; but you're in a grey area here, of using scripting techniques to parse output that's meant for a person.

Another option would be to use the pattern-matching built into the branch command, instead of grep:

```
git branch fix*
```

If this really is for scripting purposes, you probably should process the output form `git for-each-ref` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! As @torek suggested first, there are spaces before the branch names to align up with the

```
* current_branch_name
```

Since branch names don't contain space characters (at least I don't use them)

`git branch | grep '\sfix-'`

solved my problem, because any string preceded by `\s` means that is at the beginning of the branch name. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

`git branch | grep '^  fix-'`

Note 2 spaces.